# Compile Linux kernel on one machine (host) to be installed on another (VM)

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, cross-compiling

I tried to compile the Linux kernel on the host machine to be installed in the virtual machine. The obvious gain here is performance.

I have been using the following steps after copying over the ".config" file from the VM:

```
 $ export CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=9
 $ fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-myext-0.1 kernel_image kernel_headers
```

However, I am noticing a behavior where the compilation/packaging packages symlinks for the header files rather than the header files themselves. This behavior is fine if I am installing the packages on the same machine. However, when I copy the packages to the VM and install them, all I have installed are symlinks to files that do not exist in the VM. They exist on the host machine.

Anyone knows how to fix this? I could be missing a flag or something of that sort.

Comment: Compiling the linux kernel and creating packages are definitely software development tasks, this is not off-topic.

Comment: Have you tried using buildroot to handle the build process? It will let you choose the packages and create both the kernel and the filesystem. You will only have to select the created iso file. I have successfully done this for Virtual Box VMs.